# ECR - Ngnix image with multiple sites

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm working on the deployment of multiple websites with nginx. I want to use ECS for that and create Github actions for automatic deployment on commit. The problem is that I have multiple websites for the same company, and so on, multiple repositories. How can I automatically create an image (ngnix) from different repositories and push it into ECR?

> For example, I have 3 repositories: simulator_1, simulator_2, and simulator_3, I want to automatically create a ngnix image that contains simulator_1, simulator_2, and simulator_3 and push it into ECR.

Thanks by advance

Comment: You have 2 options, 1. create 1 image per repository 2. Create 1 image containing the code of all your repositories

Comment: To create 1 image with all the repositories, you'll need to have 1 folder with the code of all your repos and 1 Docker image which copy from that unified folder and compile everything in 1 Docker image

Comment: But if I have one folder with all my code, when I update my code in 1 repo (for example simulator_1), I will have to copy all my updates to my repo "main". So I will have to commit the same thing in 2 repo, exposing me to have differences between simulator_1 and main (folder simulator_1 of main).

Comment: And If I create 1 image per repository, I will have multiple ngnix servers running, when I'm able to have only one, so it will require more performance from the server (which will be more expensive)

Comment: Each docker image and container will need a server. Ngnix won't take much performance from the server. I'd suggest having 1 server per image/container, this is the standard/good practice.

Comment: Even if you want to keep with your 1 image per several projects, other way around would be creating one image per repository and then having a master image which imports (inherit) from the other already created images; this is called "Docker layers" using one image to create another. https://vsupalov.com/docker-image-layers/

Comment: To conclude, I'd like to discourage you from doing this and just keeping it simple with 1 image=1 repository=1 nginx inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I chose to go to one image per repository / one ngnix server per repository, because it seems that ngnix doesn't take too much performance from the server.